# Image preloading

Tags: image-preloader

I'm trying to preload my images but it's not working. in my main stylesheet I created #preload and then in my html I created a preload div. In the css I did the background method to try to preload them but it doesn't work.

Comment: What about showing some code? Anyways, it should be asked at http://doctype.com/

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? you want your images to load in the background while showing the user some other thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with Javascript

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
if (document.images)
{
  pic1= new Image(100,25); 
  pic1.src="http://someplace.com/image1.gif"; 
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: what does this do exactly?  I see not callback function so I don't see any time dependencies?